# IdentityServer 3 failing under load testing

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, identityserver3, serilog

We are using IdentityServer 3 together with the Entity Framework package as the persistence layer. Using Serilog for trace/logging outputs

The current version we are using is 2.6.0

When put under some basic load tests, for example making requests with a valid token to our api host: https://oauth-something.co.uk/connect/accesstokenvalidation

We are finding load of failures in the logs. The token we are using is valid and we've configured the LoggingOption as follows

```
options.LoggingOptions.EnableHttpLogging = true;
options.LoggingOptions.EnableWebApiDiagnostics = true;
options.LoggingOptions.EnableKatanaLogging = true;
options.LoggingOptions.WebApiDiagnosticsIsVerbose = true;
```

Any guidance on what might be causing this or how to get to the logging to give more relevant details about the cuase would be much appreciated

An example entry in the log:

```
2017-02-09 16:50:12.093 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.0934966Z] Request received, Method=POST, Url=https://oauth-something.co.uk/connect/accesstokenvalidation, Id=7fb64bc6-0509-4661-ad21-ab7c7380d51c, Message='https://oauth-something.co.uk/connect/accesstokenvalidation'

2017-02-09 16:50:12.093 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.0934966Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.MessageHandlers', Id=7fb64bc6-0509-4661-ad21-ab7c7380d51c, Operation=DependencyScopeHandler.SendAsync

2017-02-09 16:50:12.093 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.0934966Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.MessageHandlers', Id=7fb64bc6-0509-4661-ad21-ab7c7380d51c, Operation=PassiveAuthenticationMessageHandler.SendAsync

2017-02-09 16:50:12.093 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.0934966Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=7fb64bc6-0509-4661-ad21-ab7c7380d51c, Message='Route='controller:AccessTokenValidation'', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController

2017-02-09 16:50:12.093 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.0934966Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=7fb64bc6-0509-4661-ad21-ab7c7380d51c, Message='AccessTokenValidation', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController

2017-02-09 16:50:12.093 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.0934966Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=7fb64bc6-0509-4661-ad21-ab7c7380d51c, Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController

2017-02-09 16:50:12.093 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.0934966Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=7fb64bc6-0509-4661-ad21-ab7c7380d51c, Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create

2017-02-09 16:50:12.093 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.0934966Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=41a2f1bd-a654-4d5f-9265-953acda437c3, Message='IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AccessTokenValidationController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create

2017-02-09 16:50:12.093 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.0934966Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=41a2f1bd-a654-4d5f-9265-953acda437c3, Message='IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AccessTokenValidationController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController

2017-02-09 16:50:12.093 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.0934966Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=41a2f1bd-a654-4d5f-9265-953acda437c3, Operation=AccessTokenValidationController.ExecuteAsync

2017-02-09 16:50:12.093 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.0934966Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.Action', Id=41a2f1bd-a654-4d5f-9265-953acda437c3, Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction

2017-02-09 16:50:12.093 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.0934966Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Action', Id=41a2f1bd-a654-4d5f-9265-953acda437c3, Message='Selected action 'Post()'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction

2017-02-09 16:50:12.093 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.0934966Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.ModelBinding', Id=41a2f1bd-a654-4d5f-9265-953acda437c3, Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync

2017-02-09 16:50:12.093 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.0934966Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.ModelBinding', Id=41a2f1bd-a654-4d5f-9265-953acda437c3, Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync

2017-02-09 16:50:12.109 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.0934966Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.Filters', Id=41a2f1bd-a654-4d5f-9265-953acda437c3, Message='Action filter for 'Post()'', Operation=NoCacheAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync

2017-02-09 16:50:12.109 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.1092195Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Filters', Id=41a2f1bd-a654-4d5f-9265-953acda437c3, Operation=NoCacheAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync

2017-02-09 16:50:12.109 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.1092195Z] Level=Warn, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=41a2f1bd-a654-4d5f-9265-953acda437c3, Message='Cancelled', Operation=AccessTokenValidationController.ExecuteAsync

2017-02-09 16:50:12.109 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.1092195Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=7fb64bc6-0509-4661-ad21-ab7c7380d51c, Message='IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AccessTokenValidationController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create

2017-02-09 16:50:12.109 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.1092195Z] Level=Warn, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.MessageHandlers', Id=41a2f1bd-a654-4d5f-9265-953acda437c3, Message='Cancelled', Operation=PassiveAuthenticationMessageHandler.SendAsync

2017-02-09 16:50:12.109 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.1092195Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=7fb64bc6-0509-4661-ad21-ab7c7380d51c, Message='IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AccessTokenValidationController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController

2017-02-09 16:50:12.109 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.1092195Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=7fb64bc6-0509-4661-ad21-ab7c7380d51c, Operation=AccessTokenValidationController.ExecuteAsync

2017-02-09 16:50:12.109 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.1092195Z] Level=Warn, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.MessageHandlers', Id=41a2f1bd-a654-4d5f-9265-953acda437c3, Message='Cancelled', Operation=DependencyScopeHandler.SendAsync

2017-02-09 16:50:12.109 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.1092195Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.Action', Id=7fb64bc6-0509-4661-ad21-ab7c7380d51c, Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction

2017-02-09 16:50:12.109 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.1092195Z] Sending response, Method=POST, Url=https://oauth-something.co.uk/connect/accesstokenvalidation, Id=41a2f1bd-a654-4d5f-9265-953acda437c3, Message='Cancelled'

2017-02-09 16:50:12.109 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.1092195Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Action', Id=7fb64bc6-0509-4661-ad21-ab7c7380d51c, Message='Selected action 'Post()'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction

2017-02-09 16:50:12.109 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.1092195Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=41a2f1bd-a654-4d5f-9265-953acda437c3, Operation=AccessTokenValidationController.Dispose

2017-02-09 16:50:12.109 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.1092195Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=41a2f1bd-a654-4d5f-9265-953acda437c3, Operation=AccessTokenValidationController.Dispose

2017-02-09 16:50:12.109 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-09T16:50:12.1092195Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.ModelBinding', Id=7fb64bc6-0509-4661-ad21-ab7c7380d51c, Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync

2017-02-09 16:50:12.109 +00:00 [Debug] HTTP Response Exception

System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.

   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()

   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<ExecuteAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Web.Http.Owin.PassiveAuthenticationMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<InvokeCore>d__0.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Owin.ConfigureHttpLoggingExtension.<<ConfigureHttpLogging>b__0>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Comment: these logs don't show much, imo

Comment: is that because we have set some configuration around loggingoptions or something similar incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using Windows Server as the IIS host as your load testing target. Windows desktop machines have a very limited number of concurrent connections to IIS (10x IIRC) will result in this issue (I had a similar set of errors).